# How do I get a block configuration value in a module?

Tags: 8, blocks

I created a custom block that contains a form field.

This is my `blockSubmit()` method.

```
public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Save our custom settings when the form is submitted.
    $this->setConfigurationValue('my_text_field', $form_state->getValue('my_text_field'));
}
```

Now I want to access the *my_text_field* value from outside the custom block class.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can load the block configuration entity, and get the settings.

```
$block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load($block_id);
if ($block) {
  $settings = $block->get('settings');
  $my_text_field = $settings['my_text_field'];
}
```

`$block_id` is the machine name you see in the block layout when you save the block.

**Edit: Store module configuration**

If you want to store configuration for modules don't use a block form, but use a configuration form. Reference https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/working-with-configuration-forms
(see comment from @Berdir)

**Dump all blocks and their settings**

```
$blocks = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::loadMultiple();
foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
  $settings = $block->get('settings');
  var_dump([$key => $settings]);
}
```

Comment: Getting Fatal error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Comment: Wrong block_id? Try for example `Block::load('bartik_branding')`. Better we check if the block exists. I add this to the code.

Comment: Correct answer technically but IMHO, this smells like an anti-pattern.. if your configuration *is* global, then make it global configuration. Block configuration is per-block on purpose, so you could have multiple blocks with different settings or even have blocks in page_manager or so.

Comment: Good point, I add this to the answer.

Comment: @4k4 block_id is correct, still facing the same issue.

Comment: @NikhilBanait, for debugging you can dump all blocks and their settings, see edit.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `BLOCK_ID` with your block's ID and dig the variables in it using get function

```
$config = \Drupal::config('block.block.BLOCK_ID');
$config->get('settings.my_text_field');
```

Answer (score -2):

I understand that the code above sounds like it should work, Block::load($bid) and $bid is from the annotation of the Block class. But the start of my code is this:

```
/**
 * Provides a 'SearchFiltersBlock' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *  id = "search_filters_block",
 *  admin_label = @Translation("Filters"),
 * )
 */
class SearchFiltersBlock extends BlockBase {
```

yet, ::load('search_filters_block') returns NULL.

I tried this: Block::loadMultiple() to see what blocks existed and i see one with the id "filters" and it has plugin value "search_filters_block".

No idea.